# Growing "blast" of light animation from center of page

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

Using CSS I'd like to animate a radial-gradient circle to expand the full length and width of the page (to fully white) and then reverse this animation (return to original state). This should look like a gradual "blast" of white from the center and fade to fully white once reaching full width/height, however my white background starts transitioning too early. How do I achieve this?

scss

```
    .container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      text-align: center;
      background: black;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .flash-container {
        animation: grow 5s 2s linear forwards;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        z-index: 4;

        #flash {
            background: radial-gradient(circle, white, transparent 10%);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
    }

    @keyframes grow {
        to {
            transform: scale(1000);
            background: white;
        }
    }
```

html

```html
      <div class="container">
        <div class="flash-container">
          <div class="flash"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zv3bmw8j/2/

Comment: Have you tried to just simply animate the gradient rather than the box?  You are currently trying to resize an element, which could have sever limitations in a responsive environment.

Comment: Here is an example of a codepen user doing exactly what I am proposing. Accept he is animating a box shadow which would be far better and easier to animate. https://codepen.io/mpsinghk/pen/JBVQbp

Comment: Maybe you want https://jsfiddle.net/Lpjb10rn/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your CSS to use the box-shadow method as I quoted above. This would need more tweaks to do as it was being built on a hover method. Just change the percentage value from 0% - 100% and you should be solid.  I also made a change to the HTML format and removed the inner flash div.

https://jsfiddle.net/q9n6adLp/

```
.flash-container {
    animation: grow 5s 2s linear forwards;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 4;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30vw 40vw rgba(241,244,0,1);
  .flash {
        background: radial-gradient(circle, white, transparent 10%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 100%;
    }


}
```

Comment: This seems like the right way to do it - not using radial-gradient. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped!